# How to update key value in immutable while filtering over List of Maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I have an immutable List that looks like this:

```
 this.state = {
      suggestedUsers: fromJS([
                        {
                          user: {
                            client_user_id: "1234567890",
                            full_name: "marty mcfly",
                            image: "imageURL",
                            role_name: "Associate Graphic Designer",
                            selected: false
                           }
                         },
                         {
                          user: {
                            client_user_id: "0987654321",
                            full_name: "doc",
                            image: "imageURL",
                            role_name: "Software Engineer",
                            selected: false
                           } 
                         }                
                       )]
```

This is used in a div that displays this information in the UI. 
When I click on the div, I have a function that is fired that looks like this:

```
    selectUser(clientUserId){

    // set assessments variable equal to the current team from the state
    let assessments = fromJS(this.state.suggestedUsers)

    let selectAssessor

    // set a variable called selectedUsers equal to the results of filtering over the current suggestedUsers from the state
    let selectedUsers = assessments.filter((obj) => {

        // store immutable retrieval of the client user id in a variable called userId
        let userId = obj.getIn(["user", "client_user_id"])

        // when the user clicks 'Add' user, if the id of the user matches the selected user id
        // the user, represented here by obj, is pushed into the selectedUsers array stored in the state.
        if(userId === clientUserId){
            return obj.setIn(["user", "selected"], true)
        }

        // If the user id is not equal to the selected user, that team member is kept in the
        // current team array represented by the state. 
        return userId !== clientUserId
    })

        // update the state with the current representation of the state determined by the user
        // selected team members for assessment requests
        this.setState({
          suggestedUsers: selectedUsers
        })

    }
```

The core of my question is this:

I would like to update the value of the 'selected' key in the users object to false, when this function is invoked.

I'm aware that I can't mutate the List I'm filtering over directly, but I've tried may different approaches to getting the selected value updated (i.e. using updateIn, and setIn). I know I need to set the result of calling setIn to a variable, and return that to the List I'm filtering over, but I can't get the value to update in the existing List. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I've verified that this works the way it should when I change the value manually. How can I change it with immutable by updating this one List.

=========================================================================

Thank you to the community for your feedback. Filtering, and mapping did turn out to be overkill. Using immutability-helper, I am able to update the selected value of a particular user at the index that is clicked. One caveat that was not mentioned is using merge to bring your updated data into your previous data. After updating with immutability helper, I push the updated value into an array, then make it a List, and merge it into my original data. Code below:

```
let users = this.state.teamAssessments

let selectedArray = []

users.map((obj, index) => {

    let objId = obj.getIn(["user", "client_user_id"])

    if(objId === clientUserId){

        const selectedUser = update(this.state.teamAssessments.toJS(), {

            [index]: { 

                user : {

                    selected: {

                        $set: true

                    }

                }

            }

        })

        selectedArray.push(selectedUser)

    }

})

let updatedArray = fromJS(selectedArray).get(0)

let mergedData = users.merge(updatedArray)

this.setState({

    teamAssessments: mergedData

})
```

Comment: There may be a way to do what you want, but I highly suggest just breaking your logic into multiple loops. Either do a map then filter, or do an each and push the results into a temporary array.

Comment: @GJK But how do you update the value of the state? I can break it into separate loops, but the way that immutable works, it needs to be updated in  a specific way. I can't just set obj.setIn(["key", "valueToUpdate"], true).

Comment: I'd like to avoid pushing into a temporary array. Immutable must be able to update a boolean in an object that has a deeply nested value, and have that update reflected.

Comment: Your problem is that you're using Immutable and filter together. If you were using mutable objects, you could mutate the object during the filter (although it's a bad idea). If you were using a map _and_ a filter, you could have Immutable return the correct values. However, you're trying to use both together and it's simply not going to work. The filter function simply wasn't designed that way, and Immutable isn't going to let you use the normal workarounds.

Comment: @GJK How could I use map to update the state of one object in the List, and return the entire List to the state, with the updated object inside it? I'm able to update one object, but not sure how to insert into the List on the state.

Comment: You should probably familiarize yourself with the [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). If you put your if-statement in the map and leave the ID comparison in the filter you'll have what you want.

Comment: I'm very familiar with good ole map. It's getting the updated Immutable value back into the one List on the state, and returning it, that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper). Basically, instead of cloning the entire object you just modify small pieces of the object and re-set the state after you are finished.

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const newData = update(myData, {
  x: {y: {z: {$set: 7}}},
  a: {b: {$push: [9]}}
});

this.setState({varName: newData});
```

In other words, I would ditch the fromJS and the modifying of the array while enumerating it. First, enumerate the array and create your updates. Then, apply the updates separately. Also, to me the "selected" var seems redundant as you know if they are selected because the name of the array after filtration is "selectedUsers."

Comment: I like this idea, though I'd imagine immutable will let me update an object without an additional library. The reason I need selected is because I'd like to have one data object that has a selected value set by the user. Having them set like that determines downstream behavior where the data is passed through one function, and handled differently depending on whether that value is true or false.

Comment: I see immutability helper is also mentioned in the React docs, and it works fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is mentioned but the docs also state to start using the third party library. Please check answer off if you are satisfied :)

Comment: How can I update one object in the List, but return the entire List to the state with the updated object?

Comment: Call update, push into the list, and assign that to a new object. Then set state of that new object.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, here's what I would suggest:

```
selectUser(clientUserId) {
    let suggestedUsers = this.state.suggestedUsers.map(
        userBlock =>
            userBlock.setIn(
                ['user', 'selected'],
                userBlock.getIn(['user', 'client_user_id']) === clientUserId
            )
     );
     this.setState({
         suggestedUsers,
     });
}
```

To confirm -- you are just trying to modify `state.suggestedUsers` to have `selected` be true for the selected user, and false for everyone else? Sounds perfect for Immutable's `map` function (rather than `filter`, which will just return the elements of the list for which your predicate function returns something truthy).

BTW, you have an error in your object passed into `fromJS` -- you need an extra `},` after the first `assessor_assessment` block.